# Simple jQuery working on Chrome, not on Firefox & other browsers

Tags: jquery, css, cross-browser, show-hide

I wrote those simple lines in order to show an `.elemproduct div` only if it has a background-image set.

I developed under Chrome and just realised that this code is only working under Webkit browsers.  When failing, it shows up every `.elemproduct` as if the `if` statement was not recognized.

```
function hideBox() {
  var $bg = $('.elemproduct');

  $bg.each(function() { 
     if ($(this).css("background-image") === "url(####)") {   
        return true; 
     }
     else {
        $(this).show();
     }
  });

  return true;
};
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: the background image property can be written in different ways. try checking if it contains the path, rather than equals to url(path)

Comment: Any chance of a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduces this problem?

Comment: Would it perhaps work better for you to put the background in a css class, then use the jquery .hasClass() - I know this is NOT the answer to the question but it might be to the problem you are trying to resolve. ( thus a comment not an answer )

Comment: @Mark I could but this is not possible in my case, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest that it might be because the `background-image` is never going to be exactly equal (`===`) to the path of the (presumably) image directory `http://www.infiniscale.com/beta/`.

If you want to simply hide those `.elemproduct` elements without a `background-image` it seems a little easier to use:

```
function hideBox() {
    var $eP = $('.elemproduct');
    $eP.each(

    function() {
        if (!$(this).css('background-image') || $(this).css('background-image') == 'none') {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
}

hideBox();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vsAhM/1/).

---

**Edited** to compensate with the problem that an empty `url()` in the `background` (or `background-image`) property is filled with the URL of the current page. This makes for quite a bulky `if` statement, but it does at least work reliably (so far as I can currently tell), which is an improvement on the above. Latest iteration:

```
function hideBox() {
    var href = document.location;
    var $eP = $('.elemproduct');
    $eP.each(

        function() {
        var imgString = $(this).css('background-image');
        var srcString = imgString.replace('url(','').replace(')','');
            if (!imgString || imgString == 'none' || srcString == href) {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
}
hideBox();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vsAhM/5/).

---

**Edited** and amended the above, to remove the unnecessary variable (`srcString`) and its multiple calls to `.replcace()`:

```
function hideBox() {
    var href = document.location;
    var $eP = $('.elemproduct');
    $eP.each(

        function() {
        var imgString = $(this).css('background-image');
            if (!imgString || imgString == 'none' || imgString.indexOf(href) > -1) {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
}
hideBox();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vsAhM/6/).

---

**Edited** in response to comment from OP:

> I'm trying to get it working but under chrome everything is shown, IE everything is hidden. Even if I see that your code works under jsfiddle ... I'm not understanding everything, i.e `imgString.indexOf(href) > -1`.

The `if` tests for three conditions:

1. `!imgString`, if there's no string returned from the `background-image` property of the `.css()` method.
2. `imgString == 'none'`, because jQuery (sometimes, or possibly always) returns 'none' if there is no defined `background-image`.
3. `imgString.indexOf(href) > -1`. This looks at the `imgString` variable to see if it contains the string contained by the variable `href`. If the string is found it returns the position at which it was found; if it was not found it returns `-1`.

   ```
   var string = "abcdef";
   alert(string.indexOf('a')); // alerts: 0
   ```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/68fbJ/).

```
    alert(string.indexOf('bc')); // alerts: 1
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/68fbJ/1/).

```
    alert(string.indexOf('ef')); // alerts: 4
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/68fbJ/2/).

```
    alert(string.indexOf('x')); // alerts: -1
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/68fbJ/3/).

This is to check that the empty `url()` in CSS isn't simply being filled automatically by the browser.

---

**Edited** after being pointed at the URL for the page and finding that the use of PHP and GET made things a tad more awkward than I'd imagined.

Using the following in the console (certainly in Chromium) worked:

```
$('.elemproduct').each(
    function() {
        if ($(this).css('background-image') == 'url(' + document.location.toString().substring(0, document.location.href.toString().indexOf('index')) + ')') {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
```

The above, working in JS Fiddle and implemented into the `hideBox()` function:

```
// in real life use:
// var urlString = document.location.href;
var urlString = 'http://www.infiniscale.com/beta/index.php?id=48';


function hideBox() {
    var href = document.location;
    var $eP = $('.elemproduct');
    $eP.each(
        function(){
            if ($(this).css('background-image') == 'url(' + urlString.substring(0,urlString.indexOf('index')) + ')'){
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
}
hideBox();
```

A demonstration of the above is available at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vsAhM/7/)!

Comment: Your code doesnt works but I see what you mean ... 
I wrote a kinda similar code at first, but this mean that the things I want to be hidden are going to be shown during page loading ... then hidden when processing js.
I'm still searching

Comment: What browser are you using? It works for me, in Chromium 12, Firefox 7 and Opera 11.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vsAhM/2/ 
actually working under jsfiddle but only when the whole background property is clear, I'm trying to target only the background-image

Comment: I've edited, and amended, to come up with something that works (so far as I can tell) reliably. Take a look..?

Comment: Hmm ... I'm trying to get it working but under chrome everything is shown, IE everything is hidden. 
Even if I see that your code works under jsfiddle ... 
I'm not understanding everything, i.e imgString.indexOf(href) > -1.

Comment: <div class="elemproduct" style="background: transparent url() top left no-repeat;">
</div>

Comment: an element with no bg is exactly the code above, so respecting your formatting ... I've no js error running your script I really can't tell why this is outputting this

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is a very good workaround. I give you the url of the page if you spot anything ... : 
http://www.infiniscale.com/beta/index.php?id=48
the .elemproduct div are the boxes on the bottom of the right sidebar.
Again : Chrome, FF, Safari, Opera showing all, IE showing none.

Comment: Okay David, take a good breathe and watch the solution : 
I'm using this code under modx cms, which was actually adding the base-url to every url field to get relative path to work. 
So not writing any background-image property outputted a none (or not set for some browsers) value, just writing url() outputted url(http://thebaseurl.com/).
And now, using substring, i got it working: chrome is showing url(link/) and firefox url("link/"), this means one variable for each browser to check ... enough to drive me quite crazy xD.
Thanks a lot man cya soon